# Adjust "NOW()" timezone

Tags: php, mysql

Right now my query looks like this (relevant part):

```
UPDATE last_seen=NOW()
```

But it inserts a time which is 2 hours earlier than mine. Is there any way to adjust it?

Thanks

Comment: The `NOW()` contains the time in server's timezone

Comment: @w0rldart Yes, but obviously i need to adjust it in this case :)

Comment: @Johan, I've given you a detailed answer with different ways to fix your problem... hope you find it useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the timezone on your DB.. take a look this post. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3451971/1227435

This is another great resource:

[Having Timezone problems with PHP and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053252/having-timezone-problems-with-php-and-mysql)

Comment: Assuming your using a mySQL DB. What DB are you using?

Comment: Yea its mySQL, sorry for not mentioning that. So i just pass the timezone at the end of my query?

Comment: Did you get it? Look @ UTC_TIMESTAMP()

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to try something like so:

Have an `hidden input` to collect user's timezone

```
<input type="hidden" name="offset" class="offset">
$('.offset').val(new Date().getTimezoneOffset());
```

Then get it before the update and convert it to seconds like so

```
$offset    = intval($_REQUEST['_offset']) * 60;
```

Finally add it to `time()`:

```
$now = time() + $offset;
```

Doing the above, you have a variable with the client's time in his timezone. If you don't want that, and want a common time for everybody just set your time zone with this in your `index.php`:

```
date_default_timezone_set('TIMEZONE IN HERE'); //Supported timezone list: http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php
```

But it's better if you set it in your `php.ini` (the timezone) or changing server's timezone (Debian/Ubuntu: `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like MySQL is not on the same timezone as you.

You have some options:

- Set the timezone for MySQL.
- Use PHP to set the date before storing.
- Store as a UTC timestamp and then *display* correct local time. More code, but I recommend.

Comment: What would be a valid date format for a `timestamp`, if using php date function?

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman//5.5/en/time-zone-support.html you need to set MySQL's notion` of timezone. Hope that helps...