# PHP Country Time for SQL

Tags: php

I am from India and My website server is located in UK. When ever I use the now() function in PHP, it takes the server time which is UK time. Also when I use the Query

```
"select * from tblAttendance where DATE(AttDate) =DATE(now())  Order by EmpID "
```

This takes the time from the Server, So for me to get the current date attendance I need to wait till 10:30 AM my time as only then its a new day as per the server time.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: What is the question? How to set the timezone correctly? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html

Comment: use "bool date_default_timezone_set ( string $timezone_identifier )" in php ti change the time zone 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php 
and for mysql time check out bellow post
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-to-set-time-zone-of-mysql

Comment: @parag that will only affect the PHP time, mysql's time could still be off.

Comment: @chris85, yes comment is update for mysql time

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32872549/3283363

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set timezone like this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the help But I am not sure whether I am doing the right thing,          date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$q= mysql_query("select * from tblAttendance where DATE(AttDate) =DATE(now())  Order by EmpID "); This Again has the same issue, Is there anything else I need to do

Comment: now() is the mysql function. So you have to set the mysql server timezone as well by running this query. SET time_zone = "+05:30";

Answer (score 0):

You need `date_default_timezone_set()` to set timezone to set and get timezone

[date_default_timezone_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

[Timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

and store this time to database.

Get date from php and apply to mysql query as follows.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$date=date('Y-m-d'); // current date
$q= mysql_query("select * from tblAttendance where DATE(AttDate) ='".$date."' Order by EmpID ");
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the help But I am not sure whether I am doing the right thing,          date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$q= mysql_query("select * from tblAttendance where DATE(AttDate) =DATE(now())  Order by EmpID "); This Again has the same issue, Is there anything else I need to do